# grunt uglify not distorting variable names

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm using grunt uglify and it doesn't seem to be mangling variable names. My "God" object is called "Porsche" and it keeps that and all it's functions readable as you can see here:

[image]

And this is my Gruntfile config:

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',
        mangle: {
            except: ['jQuery', 'jquery']
        }
    },
    build: {
        src: [ 
            'assets/js/**/*.js'
        ],
        dest: 'assets/js/prod/all.min.js'
    }
}
```

I want it to completely mangle everything, saving bytes on function names. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured it out:

```
uglify: {
    options: {                  
        mangle: {
            toplevel: true
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `mangle: false` to prevent changes to your variable and function names:

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',
        mangle: false
    },
    build: {
        src: [ 
            'assets/js/**/*.js'
        ],
        dest: 'assets/js/prod/all.min.js'
    }
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#no-mangling) to see another example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I would like uglify to mangle all my variable names (make them shorter / unreadable). It doesn't seem to be doing this..

Comment: He wants to MANGLE, not preventing. I'm having the same problem that my variable names stay readable.

Comment: I wasn't able to work it out Mick, if you can.. please let me know! Also submit it as an answer and I'll mark it.